# Handling "#Value!" in an Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got an Excel formula that strips off some characters in certain circumstances.  In this example, I have a list of Baseball players' last names and whether they're a Rookie (designated by "RC").  Here's a sample subset:

```
Player
--------
Trout
Knebel
Stevenson RC
Giolito
Franco
Lagares
Rosario RC
Lindor
Buxton
Correa
Frazier RC
```

So I use the following formula to keep only the "RC" piece (the names are in column H):

```
=TRIM(MID(H64, FIND(" ", H64), LEN(H64)))
```

This works perfectly for any record which contains the "RC", but for the others it fills the cell with "#Value!".

```
Player
--------
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
RC
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
RC
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
RC
```

Is there something I can add to this formula so it leaves an empty cell instead of one with useless information (for my purposes, because I do understand the error designation is important)?

Comment: **=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(H64, FIND(" ", H64), LEN(H64))),"")**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Much cleaner and more versatile.  If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
  =IFERROR(TRIM(MID(H64, FIND(" ", H64), LEN(H64))),"")
```

This is a general way of handling any formula that can return an error.

Comment: Didn't know about the IFERROR function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would probably have chosen:

```
=IF(RIGHT(H64,3)=" RC","RC","")
```

as shorter and requiring fewer functions.

Comment: Also works for people who have double-surnames (e.g. [George **Van Haltren**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Van_Haltren))

Comment: It's a nice solution, but not versatile in that part of it must be hard-coded.